# python-like interpolation of string in coffeescript

Tags: python, string, coffeescript, string-interpolation, language-comparisons

I have such namespace with errors

```
errorMessages=
  error404Find: "Hosts not found"
  error404FindByHost: "Host - #{hostName} - not found"
  error400: "No host"
```

hostName should be assigned to **null** and overrided in function like:

```
this.hostName = 'smth'
```

or can I use something like in python:

```
errorMessages=
  {'error404Find': "Hosts not found"
  'error404FindByHost': "Host - {hostName} - not found"
  'error400': "No host"}
errorMessages['error404FindByHost'].format(hostName='smth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all those entries a functions, then apply a dictionary to them with arguments:

```
errorMessages=
  error404Find:-> "Hosts not found"
  error404FindByHost:-> "Host - #{@hostName} - not found"
  error400:-> "No host"

alert errorMessages["error404FindByHost"].apply hostName:"host1"
```